# BIOS INT 13 call, what does "1st hard disk" or "2ed hard disk" mean?

Tags: disk, bios

From wikipedia "BIOS interrupt 13th" page, we can see the following [drive table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_13H#Drive_Table):

Drive Table

- DL = 00h  1st floppy disk ( "drive A:" )
- DL = 01h  2nd floppy disk ( "drive B:" )
- DL = 80h  1st hard disk
- DL = 81h  2nd hard disk

What I am confused about is that what determines the order of disks?

Is it the boot priority that we can set in BIOS setup menu?

Here is my BIOS boot setting:
[image: My BIOS boot setting]

So does it mean that with DL=0x80, we can read/write the first device and with DL=0x81 and 0x82, we can read/write the remaining devices?

Comment: Flagged for closing: "Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question."

Comment: @ray Could you please tell me which part makes you confused? :)

Comment: Can you tell us instead what part makes you confused? The first hard disk is the one configured as the primary drive (by cabling, jumper, or in the BIOS), usually the boot drive, and the second is an additional drive that is not the primary. (The primary used to be called the *master*, and additional drives were called *slaves*; that terminology is probably not politically correct nowdays.) In a standard DOS system, drive C: would be the first hard disk.

Comment: @KenWhite Hi, thank you. I add a picture which shows my boot setting, so I can access these devices by INT 13th with DL value ranging from 0x80 to 0x82? Am I right?

Comment: I understood the question. He was asking what determines the order of hard drives used when processing the value of the DL register. Like, what determines which hard drive is the first, second, etc. He mentioned the BIOS boot order as one possibility he suspects might decide it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BIOS determines the order of the drives (at least with the BIOS call).

The drive you booted to will be the first hard drive.  For the other drives, there are no well defined rules about it. Different BIOSes behave differently (AMI vs Phoenix).  Some will list them per the boot order, others will simply list them in the order they were detected (SATA before USB).